# False proof that the wedge of $n$ circles is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with this use of Van Kampen's theorem to no avail. Construct the space $X$ as follows: Start with the disjoint union of $S^2$ with $n$ segments ($S^2\sqcup[a_1, b_2]\sqcup\ldots\sqcup[a_n, b_n]$). Then, identify the north pole of the sphere with each $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and the south pole of the sphere with each $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$, joining the two poles with $n$ strings that only intersect at their extremities. I am almost sure that this space if homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of a sphere with a bouquet of $n$ circles and it is clear to me that $\pi_1(X)$ is just a free group with $n$ generators.

But let us decompose $X$ as follows: Let $U$ be a small neighborhood of $U' = [a_1, b_1)\cup\ldots\cup[a_n, b_n)$ (That is, the $n$ strings, open at one end and glued at the north pole at the other end. We also need to include a small open cap of the north pole since this needs to be open). This is a contractible space, just a open disk with $n$ segments sticking out.

Let $V$ be the complement of $U'$, which is just a sphere without the north pole, also contractible. The intersection of $U$ and $V$ is the small open cap of the north pole with the pole removed, which is a path connected space. But this cannot be, unless $X$ is simply connected. What did I miss?

Comment: The set $V$ is not open at the south pole. If you were to make it open by including $[b_i, b_i - \varepsilon)$, the intersection of $U$ and $V$ would fail to remain path-connected.

Comment: @JuliusJ. This should be an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SvK Theorem requires open subsets whose (pairwise) intersections are path-connected.

The set $V$ is *not* open at the south pole, so SvK does not apply.

What if we slightly expand $V$ by adding the segments $[b_i,b_i-\varepsilon)$ to it, making it open? Then the intersection of $U$ and $V$ has multiple path-components, so SvK again does not apply.